# Migrate fields from one table to another

Tags: sql, elixir, ecto

I'm new to Elixir.  I have 2 tables, and need to merge them together. I don't know if I need a join table, or I can just smash it all together

Table 1 `Notes`

```
content: String
createdAt: DateTime
id: ID!
updatedAt: DateTime
```

Table 2 `Activities`

```
at: DateTime // different then CreatedAt in Notes
id: ID! // different then ID in Notes
note: String // This is the same as Content in Notes
type: ActivityType = NOTE // ActivityType will always be NOTE
```

What I want to do is merge all the LeadNotes into Activities. I think what I have is way off

```
use Ecto.Migration

def up do
  create table(“LeadNote_ActivityNote_joins") do
    add :content, references: :LeadNote
    add :id, references: :LeadNote
  end

  # create new Activities with an existing Note
  execute(
    "INSERT INTO activities(note)"
  )

  # Insert into the joined table the activity and leadnote ids
  execute(
    "INSERT INTO LeadNote_ActivityNote_joins(LeadNote_id, LeadNote_content)
      SELECT .... FROM products ... RIGHT JOIN LeadNote_content ON activity_content
  )

end
```

Comment: "I have 2 tables, and need to merge them together. I dont know if I need a join table, or I can just smash it all together" - are they related one to one, one to many or many to many? This should dictate your table design

Comment: one to one. One leadnote equals one activity @Mark

Comment: Then you definitely won't need a join table - assuming you have a note and a lead activity, you can give the note record a 'lead_activity_id' that dictates which lead_activity it's associated with.

Comment: https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/2.2.11/associations.html#one-to-one gives a good example of how to add a one-to-one relationship - Elixir and Ecto have specific syntax for establishing relationships in migrations

Comment: def change do
    alter table(:notes) do
      add :lead_activity_id, references(:lead_activities)
    end
  end